# Jhipster - How to send Request/Information from Gateway to Microservice

Tags: jhipster

I am using Jhipster Microservice Archi which suit better for my need.

I am trying to find a way to send request from Gateway to Microservice, Or at least send some more user information (Phone number, email ...) to microservice. Is there is any way to do that ?

What i wanted to do is basically when an user are just freshly registered, i want to send a request from the gateway to microservice in order to create for example TaxiLocation if the authority of the user is taxi, or create a shop if the user is a Shop manager ...

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Thanks for uout help, i finally figured it out :

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do is communication between microservices, so here, the backend of your gateway wants to send request to your other microservice.
Am I correct?

If it's the case, you can read this ticket, it has been discussed:

- https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/3649

You have this tutorial too, by Xetys, from JHipster team:

- http://stytex.de/blog/2016/03/25/jhipster3-microservice-tutorial/

And, you have a specific module which can do the job too, made by Christophe, from JHipster team too:

- https://github.com/cbornet/generator-jhipster-swagger-cli

Hope, it will help you.

Comment: Theses are good approaches but as an alternative, you could add more information to the JWT token claims as long as this additional info is not sensitive data as  the token is not encrypted only base64 encoded and signed.

Comment: Thanks Dude, thats exactly what i was looking for. I ll take a deep look on it ;)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your help, i finally figured it out :

1 - Create a Feign Config with a RequestInterceptor so then request will be authentificate
public class FeignConfig {

```
@Inject
private JHipsterProperties properties;

@Bean
public RequestInterceptor requestTokenBearerInterceptor() {
    return requestTemplate -> {
        String token = Jwts.builder().
            setSubject("xxx")
            .claim("auth", "xxx")
            .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512, properties.getSecurity().getAuthentication().getJwt().getSecret())
            .compact();
        requestTemplate.header("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
    };
}
```

}

2- Create MicroserviceClient & MicroserviceClientFallback

@FeignClient(name = "xxxxxxxx", fallback = MicroserviceClientFallback.class, configuration = FeignConfig.class)
public interface MicroserviceClient {

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/createuser",
               method = RequestMethod.POST,
               produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
UserInfo createUser(UserInfo user);
```

}

@Component
public class MicroserviceClientFallback implements MicroserviceClient {

```
private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MicroserviceClientFallback.class);

@Override
public UserInfo createUser(UserInfo user) {
    log.warn("Triggered fallback for createUser : {}", user);
    return null;
}
```

}

3 - Finally Call it from a rest controller

```
@Inject
private MicroserviceClient microserviceClient;
...
microserviceClient.createUser(userInfo);
```

Comment: Can you create a detail step by step guide for the rest of us who encouter the same issue. Thanks.